# Broken title in audio files?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediascanner

I have been running into a problem in which the title/artist tags of my audio files are not showing up properly.

Here are two screenshots of the most pertinent problem with the files https://imgur.com/a/4uhOG

Thinking it was a tagging issue, I used MP3Tag to rename/retag the files. I tried foobar as well too and it didn't work.

I tried modifying the character encoding of the files in foobar, assuming that the metadeta charset were not properly encoded but that failed too.

The format of the files did not matter, the files were a mix of FLAC and MP3 formats.

The only trend I managed to draw out was that it happens more frequently on non-english tracks, even then most other tracks, english or otherwise, works fine.

I cleared the MediaScanner, swap between music players, change ROMs and directory to no avail. On my PC however, it shows up fine.

Anyone knows of a solution to this, or is it the nature of the way the MediaScanner parses the files?

- Galaxy Note 4 Snapdragon.
- Temasek's UNOFFICIAL cm-13.0 [v7.2].
- Sandisk 128GB extSDcard.